# When I integrate one CSS with another, why is the font styling of one CSS changing to that of the other?

Tags: css

I have an image slider (CSS based) customised to my specifications (font styles, size etc). Then I have another CSS having 6 download buttons. But when I try to combine and integrate both of them into my HTML page, why are the CAPTION'S font sizes, their styling, caption positioning etc changing?

ALSO note that in the individual DOWNLOAD BUTTON page, when I hover oved the DOWNLOAD BUTTON, the text "DOWNLOAD" still shows in WHITE colour. But after integrating both the CSSpages, when I hover over DOWNLOAD button, its colour changes from white to BLACK! Why is it happening? 
Please have a look at these pages:
THE INDIVIDUAL SLIDER page: [www.aamaodisha.org/nivoslider.html](http://www.aamaodisha.org/nivoslider.html)
THE INDIVIDUAL DOWNLOAD BUTTONS page: [www.aamaodisha.org/button.html](http://www.aamaodisha.org/button.html)

When I integrate them both into a single page, they look like this:
[www.aamaodisha.org/both.html](http://www.aamaodisha.org/both.html)

I am sorry, this might be a very silly doubt of mine but I am very new to CSS properties, I just decided to try design my own website. 
I tried looking on Google on CSS chapters but couldn't help myself out. But as far as I have grasped things about CSS, I guess it has something to do with "IDs" and "Class" for the texts. I guess if I somehow change the CAPTION class in the nivoslider to an ID, it mayn't interfere with other settings. or may be change class of DOWNLOAD page CSS to some ID. But I am unable to find a way. 
Please help me out.

This is the CSS for the SLIDER:

```
a, a:visited {
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.nivo-nextNav {
    background-position:-30px 0;
    right:15px;
}
a.nivo-prevNav {
    left:15px;
}

#slider_wrapper {
  height: 390px;
}

#slider {
    margin:0px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:102px;
    width: 359px;
    height: 390px;
    background: url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

#slider img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
#slider a {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
}


.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    background:#ffffff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #4a4a4a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #4a4a4a;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #4a4a4a;

}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
.nivoSlider a {
    border:0;
    display:block;
}
/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:6;
    display:none;
}
/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%;
}
.nivo-box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
}
/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#091023;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:0.7; /* Overridden by captionOpacity setting */
    width:100%;
    z-index:8;
    }
.nivo-caption p {
    font:11px/1.5 Verdana;
    padding: 7px 50px;

}
.nivo-caption a {
    display:inline !important;
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
}
.nivo-caption a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    display:none;
}

/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:9;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0px;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
    right:0px;
}
.nivo-controlNav {
    position:absolute;
    left:73%;
    top:7px;
    margin-right:-4px; /* Tweak this to center bullets */
}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav a {
    display:block;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background:url(bullets.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    margin-right:3px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background-position:0 -22px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

This is the CSS for the DOWNLOAD BUTTONS:

```
.button {
  width: 115px;
}

.button1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:430px;
    top:410px;

}    
.button2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:632px;
    top:410px;

}  
.button3 {
    position:absolute;
    left:833px;
    top:410px;

}    
.button4 {
    position:absolute;
    left:430px;
    top:636px;

}    
.button5 {
    position:absolute;
    left:632px;
    top:636px;

}   
.button6 {
    position:absolute;
    left:833px;
    top:636px;

}   
.button a {
  display: block;
  height: 28px;
  width: 115px;

  /*TYPE*/
  color: white;
  font: bold 11px/28px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase; 

  /*GRADIENT*/  
  background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%, #009ec3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#009ec3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.button a, p {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

p {
  background: #222;
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 105px;
  margin: -27px 0 0 5px;

  /*TYPE*/
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 10px/28px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;

  /*POSITION*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;

  /*TRANSITION*/  
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s ease;
     -moz-transition: margin 0.4s ease;
       -o-transition: margin 0.4s ease;
      -ms-transition: margin 0.4s ease;
          transition: margin 0.4s ease;
}

/*HOVER*/
.button:hover .bottom {
  margin: -4px 0 0 5px;
}

.button:hover .top {
  margin: -50px 0 0 5px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

/*ACTIVE*/
.button a:active {
background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%, #009ec3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(36%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#009ec3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.button:active .bottom {
  margin: -14px 0 0 5px;
}

.button:active .top {
  margin: -30px 0 0 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `button.css` line no 74 change the selector fro `p` to `.button p`

so instead of

```
 p {
    -moz-transition: margin 0.4s ease 0s;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font: bold 10px/28px Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
    height: 25px;
    margin: -27px 0 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 105px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

it should be

```
.button p {
    -moz-transition: margin 0.4s ease 0s;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font: bold 10px/28px Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
    height: 25px;
    margin: -27px 0 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 105px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much @Clyde Lobo. That solved my problem. A whole lot of thanks :) So it should be .button p

Comment: @Amit Pattnaik : I'd recommend you to read http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ for a better understanding of css selectors

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS for the download buttons, you have this rule:

```
.button a, p {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

That applies all of those declarations to every anchor element inside an element with the class `button`, but also to every paragraph element regardless of its parent. The caption in your slider box is placed in a paragraph tag. That's why those additional styles are applied. A quick way to solve this is to add some specificity to the caption with a class, and apply the declarations to that class instead of all paragraph elements.

The best way to understand where style declarations are coming from is to use the inspector in a modern browser like Chrome or Firefox. In Chrome, try secondary-clicking on an element like the caption. Select `Inspect Element` from the contextual menu. Under `Computed Style`, you will see every declaration the browser has interpreted, and where it came from.

Comment: thank yo so much for replying so quickly. Yes, I now see that the styling inside the p class -- border radius of 4px etc -- is also making a rounded corner out of the slider caption as well. 
But I couldn't clearly get you regarding "add some specificity to the caption with a class, and apply the declarations to that class instead of all paragraph elements." :(

Comment: So if I change the above code to separately placing a and p and not together, eg - 
.button a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.button p {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

Comment: That's the idea, but try to group declarations where possible. Say you have two kinds of elements you want to select. You want them both to have green text, but you want their borders to be different. You could do something like this:
`.button a, .button p {color: green;}`
`.button a {border: 1px solid blue;}`
`.button p {border: 1px solid red;}`

Comment: Wow, that is great.. . So now I can separately give specifications about their properties!  This is so useful. Thanks a lot once again @JezenThomas

Comment: like when they have similar properties, I can group them together and when I need to give them different styles/properties, I can separately give them the way like you have explained above.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href="button.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

...................................................................

```
<link href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

here is some source for your page. As you see, the link to the slider css is after the one for the buttons. Every time you put in a css link, whatever was defined before is overwritten if the element styling is declared again. SO you have

```
a:hover, a:active {
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
```

} in your slider css, which is called second. This will overwrite your styling in button, as it is a general declaration for all **a** elements. And the color is #000 (black)

Comment: Thank you so much @Ameoo for the help. I changed that colour to white and voila! 
Being a complete novice to CSS, I wasn't able to clearly understand the tid-bits by merely looking at the codes. But this was a great lesson from you, a practical lesson -- "the link to the slider css is after the one for the buttons. Every time you put in a css link, whatever was defined before is overwritten if the element styling is declared again." Now I get it why the styling were interefering with the other settings.